# Changing machine name in ORACLE SQL

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, jdbc

I'm new to SQL development. While trying to access remote databases at work I often don't get access because my machine name is odd. I want it to copy my computer's name, but instead it looks like this:

```
select OSUSER, MACHINE from v$session where username = 'user1'

OSUSER      MACHINE

myOsName    jdbcclient
```

Running hostname or hostnamectl shows the correct name of my pc, i.e. 'Grynek-pc'. Is there a way to change the name of the machine?

OS: Ubuntu 19.04, program: SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

The properties you see in `V$SESSION` are the same as the ones you can recover using the default context ( `SYS_CONTEXT` ). There are two fields of interest for you in this case:

- MACHINE  Operating system machine name.
- TERMINAL Operating system terminal name.

An example:

1.I access from my laptop using Toad

```
SQL> select username , osuser ,  machine,terminal , program from v$session where 
     username = 'MY_DB_USER' and upper(osuser) = 'MY_OS_USER' ;

USERNAME                       OSUSER                         MACHINE                        TERMINAL                       PROGRAM
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------------
MY_DB_USER                     MY_OS_USER                     DOMAIN\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxxxxx                Toad.exe
```

In this case `MACHINE` is giving me the name of the host with the domain windows information, meanwhile terminal is giving me only the terminal name without domain information. In the program column I can see my Toad software.

2.I connect locally with sqlplus

```
SQL> host whoami
ftpcpl

SQL> select username , osuser ,  machine,terminal , program from v$session where username = 'SYS' and osuser = 'ftpcpl' ;

USERNAME                       OSUSER                         MACHINE                        TERMINAL                       PROGRAM
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------------
SYS                            ftpcpl                         my_database_server_hostname    pts/1                          sqlplus@xxxxxx
```

In my local connection, the terminal is my `tty` linux terminal session, and the machine is the local database host name.

However, often when you use middleware software such as Weblogic, Websphere or Tomcat,  Oracle `v$session` column program shows "JDBC Thin Client" and the terminal column shows "unknown". The way to trace back to where this connection comes from is by looking at the Oracle SQL*Net listener log. If you're using thin jdbc drivers, you'll typically not see as much information than if you were using thick (oci8) drivers

Answering your question, no you can't change the terminal or the machine name in the V$SESSION, those are inherited properties of the session itself. However, you can apply CONTEXT LEVEL information to your session by using DBMS_SESSION.

Check this good article:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_session

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a recent Oracle client or JDBC driver, and they should accurately report the MACHINE. If not, it's possible to spoof many of your session values, such as OSUSER and MACHINE.

Recent Oracle clients and JDBC drivers should correctly report the MACHINE. It looks like you're using a modern version of Oracle SQL Developer, but is it using a modern driver?  Check in Tools --> Preference --> Database --> Advanced for custom settings, and update your drivers if necessary.

Hopefully it won't come to this, but almost all of those [session values can be spoofed](https://www.integrigy.com/files/Integrigy_Spoofing_Oracle_Session_Information.pdf). Some of the session values are described in the [OracleConnection Interface javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_VSESSION_OSUSER). For example, OSUSER is based on the JVM property "user.name". You can fake the sessison OSUSER by adding the line `AddVMOption -Duser.name=SomeUserName` to the file "...\sqldeveloper\ide\bin\ide.conf" and restarting SQL Developer.

I wasn't able to specifically spoof MACHINE because I'm not sure how the driver obtains the hostname. (On Windows, I tried creating a fake "hostname.exe" and running `set computername=fakeName`, but neither of those worked.) If you're writing your own JDBC program the values are easy to set, for example `java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties(); props.put("v$session.terminal", "My PC!");` But I'm not sure how to do that with existing drivers used by SQL Developer.

If you can't change the MACHINE value for your IDE, send this information to whoever is creating security rules based on V$SESSION. Their access rules are not as secure as they think they are. The access rules may stop you from using SQL Developer, but they won't provide great protection against real threats.